# Adding two formulas in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I know I'm not connecting something somewhere, so I need your help.

I have made calculations in each formula and now need to add them together - simple, but not. haha

Here is my code:

Group 1 - student
Group 2 - class
Group 3 - StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type (which is divided by Absent and Tardy)

I have to add the Absences and Tardies together, but for every 3 tardies = 1 Absent.

The calculations come out correctly for each one separately, but I can't add the Absence formula + the Tardy to Absent formula.

Creating another formula with Absent + Tardy to Absent does nothing...

Formulas:

**Absent:**
if GroupName ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = "Absent" then Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type})/76*100

**Tardy to Absent:**
if GroupName ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = "Tardy" then
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 3 then 1 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 4 then 1 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 5 then 1 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 6 then 2 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 7 then 2 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 8 then 2 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 9 then 3 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 10 then 3 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 11 then 3 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 12 then 4 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 13 then 4 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 14 then 4 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 15 then 5 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 16 then 5 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 17 then 5 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 18 then 6 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 19 then 6 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 20 then 6 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 21 then 7 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 22 then 7 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 23 then 7 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 24 then 8 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 25 then 8 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 26 then 8 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 27 then 9 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 28 then 9 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 29 then 9 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 30 then 10 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 31 then 10 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 32 then 10 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 33 then 11 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 34 then 11 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 35 then 11 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 36 then 12 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 37 then 12 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 38 then 12 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 39 then 13 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 40 then 13 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 41 then 13 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 42 then 14 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 43 then 14 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 44 then 14 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 45 then 15 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 46 then 15 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 47 then 15 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 48 then 16 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 49 then 16 /76*100 else
if Count ({StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}, {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = 50 then 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a simple detail level formula called {@Absence_Equivalent} using an expression such as:

```
IF {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = "Absent" Then 1
ELSE IF {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = "Tardy" Then 1/3
ELSE 0
```

Then, SUM that formula at any grouping or grand total level you wish.

Comment: sorry, lots of comments by me...trying to figure it out...looks like I need to flip the way I've been looking at the math....this adds a tardy in increments of .33....so I need to /76 (number of days the student goes to this class) then *100 to get it in a %. How should I add that in?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the reference to 76. 
If you need % of days absent, divide the sum of the formula I proposed by number of days in the semester. There is no need to worry about the fraction because it reflects the correct weight of a Tardy case.

Comment: I just thought I should add up the absences + Tardy to Absent and then divide by the number of days the class is held (76). Maybe I don't need to do that with your formula...I keep looking at the report and going through the students with different variations and it looks to all add up correctly....so thank you very much! Much appreciated.

Comment: This is needed for a director that has to keep track of a student's absences and tardies per class and if it gets above like 10% per class, then they have to notify the parents.

Comment: Yes, this should work just fine. Sum the suggested formula at the grouping level 2 (you don't really need grouping level 3 for this) and divide by the number of days.

Use Group Sort expert to sort the students by the total sum of the suggested formula. You can also use Report, Selection Formula, Group... to show only students with a % above 10%.

Comment: And once the director feels comfortable with that exception report, look into Crystal Reports automation tools (Ken Hamady maintains a list of such tools on his web site) to automate the emailing of alerts to parents. That released the director from the responsibility of taking care of that process. It can also make it easy to include in the email a table of Absence/Tardy details so the parents feel better informed.

Comment: That sorting comment is VERY helpful...thanks! I was wondering how I was going to do that so the director didn't have to scroll through and find the ones she needed. I haven't used the 'Sum' function a lot, how do I divide it by 76? Create another formula?

Comment: What would be the formula to show only students with 10% and above? Never done that before...always used Sort Expert.

Comment: nevermind on the grouping question....I think I figured it out by playing around with it. I was getting confused by still looking at the left side of the screen with the list of all students. I noticed when I'm using the Select Expert with the 'Sum' field it pulls only the number I entered. Now I just need to understand how to divide the sum field. Many thanks for all your replies!

Comment: I also found out that the Alert function works in the same way as the Select Expert function...pretty cool, never used it before.

Comment: Hey MilletSoftwre, I checked my problem as being answered, so I'm wondering if you have not been notified of my comments. If you could, I still need help on how to divide the sum by any number (76 for this year). Thanks!

Comment: thanks for your help with everything, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Create a formula that divides the sum by 76  -- that seems like the simplest approach. If for some reason you don't want to do that, then:

Option 2: divide the detail level value by 76. For example,

```
IF {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = "Absent" Then 1/76
ELSE IF {StudentWorkList_.Excuse Type}) = "Tardy" Then 1/228
ELSE 0
```